# Mechanical method to solve trivial diagram chasing problem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

I know that in the area of "mechanical theorem proving in Geometry", there is a method (I may call it "point elimination" method) to solve some kinds of mechanical theorems proving problems in elementary geometry, and the algorithm is something like:

(1) Construct the points (and relations) involved according to the order of dependency.

(2) Eliminate the points (and relations) step by step by reversed order of dependency.

(3) You get the minimal amount of points in the game and the problem becomes an easy one.

I realize that this procedure of solving elementary geometry problems might be applied to the diagram chasing problem. Because the diagram chasing problem can be viewed as a graph problem in which "we construct the objects and arrows step by step and then figure out the relationship between them", and the "an object is unique up to unique isomorphism" in category theory is the same as "a point is determined by other points" in elementary geometry.

This idea comes to me when I was trying to prove that "the direct limit and stalk are interchangeable. i.e. $ (\lim \limits_{\longrightarrow pre} F_i)_p = \lim \limits_{\longrightarrow pre} (F_i)_p$", noticing that a stalk is just another direct limit, thus this proposition fits well in "diagram chasing" paradigm with basic ingredient in category theory, it should be solved mechanically in my simple mind...

I tried the "point(object) elimination" procedure in dealing with this proposition but I got stuck because it seems to me that there is no easy way of eliminating objects.

I wonder if the above idea makes any sense... Do I have a point here?

Update: I realize that the difficulty is to establish a verification relation $R$ releted to the proposition we want to prove. As the "elimination" precedure goes, R becomes complicated in size but simple in nature(with less objects in $R$!). So for example, what is the verification relation $R$ when it comes to "the unique isomorphism between two objects"? I failed to establish $R$ to the "the direct limit and stalk are interchangeable" proposition.

Update2: Just like analytic geometry for elementary geometry using "point elimination" method, I wonder if there is a correspondent framework for "trivial" diagram chasing problem using "object elimination" method.

Update3: The word mechanical in the title is somewhat misleading, there is no ambition here to address all the problems, but it would be sweet if we can simplify the trivial one, namely the one with basic ingredients in category theory (or without other non-categorical conditions).

Update4: Let's test this philosophy by proving the "the direct limit and stalk are interchangeable. i.e. $ (\lim \limits_{\longrightarrow pre} F_i)_p = \lim \limits_{\longrightarrow pre} (F_i)_p$" proposition, shall we? Can anyone prove this proposition by using the "object elimination" method?

You may prove it using the setting here...  We try to prove that $G$ isomorphic to $H$. First you might want to eliminate $G$, then eliminate $H$, or eliminate $H$ first, then eliminate $G$; (because $G$ and $H$ are at the same level of dependency.) and after that, you might want to eliminate $E(U_1)$ and $E(U_2)$, then $G_i$ and $G_j$, or $G_i$ and $G_j$, then $E(U_1)$ and $E(U_2)$. Finally you get a diagram with only the "original" objects $F_i(U_1),F_i(U_2),F_j(U_1),F_j(U_2)$, and a not-yet-verified relation $R$. You prove the proposition if you manage to verify $R$.
[image: setting]

Update5: I want to push the analogy to its limit. Can we view the objects in category as some kind of pseudo-points, the arrows as some kind of pseudo-vectors (maybe points and vectors with equivalence relation) in pseudo-analytic space, view the limit or colimit as maybe the median point (or whatever) of those pseudo-points. Then we may be able to build up an analytic system for category... (maybe just pseudo-vectors will be enough because what matters in category are the arrows.) It's just me being fantasizing...

Comment: I'm not qualified to say more about this specific case, but it may be worth keeping in mind that in full generality, diagram chasing problems (once well defined) are algorithmically undecidable in general; this is due to [Hutchinson, 1973 (Recursively unsolvable word problems of modular lattices and diagram-chasing)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186937390001X).

Comment: Could you please formulate the diagram chasing problem, trivial or otherwise?

Comment: It's also somewhat trivial to encode a word problem over monoids into a diagram chasing problem of a category with 1 object.

Comment: Also posted on math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665347/mechanical-method-to-solve-trivial-diagram-chasing-problem

Comment: I don’t know if this addresses your central question, but the spectral sequences approach to diagram chasing seems relevant here. Though I only know how to do this for diagrams on a square grid, if you have your starting hypothesis, it shows you (all of the?) nontrivial diagram chasing constructed maps as higher differentials. This lets you easily see what exact sequences/isomorphisms come out of different starting exactness hypotheses on your diagram, making it feel more like a mechanical problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions about diagrams in Euclidean geometry are algorithmically decidable because they can all be interpreted in $\mathbb Q$ extended with square roots, which has decidable equality.

As for category theory, it depends on the subject area.

Probably it can be done with 1950s homological algebra, for a similar reason, namely that it can be interpreted in vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$, again with decidable equality.

However, category theory has learned how to do a hell of a lot more than that since then.  Anything that can be expressed in any form of type theory given by introduction and elimination rules can equally well be encoded using commutative diagrams and universal properties. Therefore any undecidability result from symbolic logic is also one of category theory.

In particular, in 1973 André Joyal proposed a categorical version of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems.  This was finally [written up](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10482) by Alexander Gietelink Oldenziel in 2020.